# How to select the not null rows from another dataframe and take randomly its index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like below:

```
name of dataframe : ZA
             AB        AC        AF
    A1  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
    B1       NaN  0.400157  0.400157
```

I want to add later the index of a random row from each non-empty column.

Here is the code:

```
list = ['AB','AC','AF']

info_s =   pd.DataFrame(columns=['X'],index = list)

for app in list:
    if app in ZA.columns:
        ele = ZA.dropna(how='all') #didn't work  
        ele1=ele.loc[:,app].take(np.random.permutation(len(ele.index))[:1]) 
        ind = ele1.index
        info_s.loc[app, 'X'] = ind
    else:
        info_s.loc[app, 'X'] = None
```

output :

```
Index        X
AB          Only A1
AC          A1 or B1
AF          A1 or B1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## IIUC Edit:

```
ZA.notnull().apply(lambda x:np.random.choice(x[x].index)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'X'})
```

Output:

```
  index   X
0    AB  A1
1    AC  B1
2    AF  A1
```

You don't need the list nor for loop, this one-liner will do:

*Explanation*

Use `notnull` to convert to boolean, then apply lambda function to join all values of the index where booleans are true.  In a Pandas series, x[x] if x is a boolean will on return those positive indexes and values.

```
ZA.notnull().apply(lambda x: ' or '.join(x[x].index))
```

Output:

```
AB          A1
AC    A1 or B1
AF    A1 or B1
dtype: object
```

And you can do some housekeeping rename columns, reset_index, etc...

```
ZA.notnull().apply(lambda x: ' or '.join(x[x].index)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'X'})
```

Output:

```
  index         X
0    AB        A1
1    AC  A1 or B1
2    AF  A1 or B1
```

Comment: the output is without the 'or' and really i need the function random and notnull. As i said above, the code is almost done, need only to select and add the index of the row without the nan.